# n derivatives on a function of n variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, function-construction, expression-manipulation, argument-patterns

I want to derive an expression with respect to each variable of a function $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$. More precisely:

$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial_{x_i}}\right) g(f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n))$

with $n\in \mathbb N$ generic and $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is known function (for instance $ g(y) = \arcsin(y)$).

Do you know how to get a symbolic result? I think the use of blanks __ is the right way to go, but I cannot figure out how.

**Edit**

I'm looking for an output result of the form (with $n$ unspecified)

$\sum_i^n h_i(\{f^{(i...)}\})$

where $i$ is a (possibly multi-)index and $h$ some function of the partial derivatives of $f$ that depends on the known function $g$.

Comment: A possible duplication of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7876/pattern-matching-a-multivariate-derivative

Comment: I edited the question, Now the difference with that suspected 'duplicate' is more evident.

Comment: Symbolic order derivatives were introduced as a [new feature in v11.1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn111.html) (look for 'D (updated)').

Comment: @Thies-heidecke. It looks to me that even the 'D (updated)' function doesn't do the job. Indeed, first one has to define $f(x_1,x_2,..x_n)$ specifying all variables names '$x_j$' and also the number of variables $n$ itself, only then one can apply $D$ to $f$ saying it explicitly to derive in $x_1,x_2,...$. I need a more abstract approach where you don't have to give a name to all variables of $f$ in the first step.

Comment: Mathematica can't handle this unknown number of derivatives. On the other hand this is a pretty simple pure math question so it can't hurt to ask on math.stackexchange where they've probably done this already?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Mathematica can help you find the closed form result directly, but you can generate examples for given `n` as follows.

Define a generic function of an arbitrary number of variables by using a single dummy variable `x`

```
f[0][x]
```

the first entry `0` will keep track of derivatives and shows that no derivatives have been taken yet.

Then, define a derivative operation with a dummy variable `x` as follows

```
Dxi[input_, xi_] := D[input, x] /. Derivative[1][f[y_]][x_] :> f[y + xi][x]
```

this will take any input and take a derivative with respect to the dummy `x`, then any `f[y]'[x]` expressions are replaced by `f[y+xi][x]` which denotes that a derivative with respect to `xi` has been applied, e.g.,

```
Dxi[g[f[0][x]], x[i]]
```

> [image]

With this, you can generate effective derivatives on function `g[f[0][x]]` with any amount of different `x[i]`. For example, if `n=3`

```
n=3;
gderivatives=g[f[0][x]];
Do[gderivatives=Dxi[gderivatives,x[i]];,{i,1,n}];
Collect[gderivatives,Derivative[_][g][f[0][x]],FullSimplify]
```

> [image]

Staring at a few examples for lower `n` values you might come up with a general pattern how the derivatives arrange themselves. This will likely involve sets, subsets and permutations of labels and such.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I'm actually looking for a code that gives an output with $n$ left unspecified. But maybe you are right, Mathematica cannot handle it, as it should recognize the combinatorial pattern behind this derivative...