# Define an $n$-variable function with $n$ undefined?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

I would like to define an $n$-variable function with $n$ undefined. For example, I want something like this:

$$    
f(x_1, \, \dots, \, x_n) = x_1 + \dots + x_n
$$

And afterwards I want to take its derivatives with respect to x_j like this

$$    
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j} f =  1
$$

Is it possible to realise in Mathematica?

Comment: Sorry for code formatting instead of Latex, but I couldn't post it otherwise (it says that the post isn't properly formatted)

Comment: Similar questions: 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188270/derivative-of-a-function-in-undefined-dimension, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208664/n-derivatives-on-a-function-of-n-variables

Comment: Does `f[x__]:=Total[{x}]; D[f[x1,t x2,x3],x2]` work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
sum = Sum[i*Indexed[x, i], {i, 1, n}]

D[sum, Indexed[x, 5]]
(* Piecewise[{{5, n >= 5}}, 0] *)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. Thank you. But somehow it stops working in slightly more difficult example: `p = Product[Indexed[x, i] - Indexed[x, j], {j, 1, N}, {i, 1, j - 1}]; D[p, Indexed[x,5]]`
returns zero. Could you explain where the problem is?

Comment: @HomoUniversalis I wish I could answer that but I can't. I was actually surprised that it worked with `Sum`—it must be a special feature of `Sum`. As far as I know, Mathematica can't really do such calculations, where the number of variables is not fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If you have your function take in a list, so you can deal with arbitrary length inputs...

```
ff[lst_?ListQ] := Total@lst
```

Then you can do

```
xs = Array[x, 5]
(* {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]} *)

D[ff[xs], x[4]]
(* 1 *)

D[ff[xs], x[40]]
(* 0 *)
```

Slightly more complicated

```
gg[lst_?ListQ] := Times @@ lst

D[gg[xs], x[1]]
(* x[2] x[3] x[4] x[5] *)
```

Comment: In your code you specify the number of variables before taking the derivative. That's not exactly what I want.